# Batch file to make a file and then recursively run original file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo, io-redirection

So I have a script to tweak settings on my pc: `Tweak.cmd`. Naturally, some systems like some tweaks, others don't. Each tweak requires a reboot. This script runs on Windows XP to 8.1, some Windows 2000 stuff as well.

I have another batch file called `Timer.cmd`. `Timer` writes to a file how long it takes the system to run the tests.

And there is a 3rd file, `TestTweak.cmd`. `TestTweak` reads the first line from a file called `options.txt`, then removes that line from `options.txt`.

`Options.txt` looks like

> ```
> reset
> tweak1
> reset
> ...
> tweakn
> reset
> ```

Now I would like `TestTweak.cmd` to create a file called `TestMe.cmd`.

```dos
@Echo SET l0= cd "%pth%">TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l1= Call %Timer% 1 %Args% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l2= Call %Timer% 2 %Args% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l3= Call %TestTweak% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo %%l0%% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo %%l1%% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo %%l2%% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo %%l3%% >>TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l0=>>TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l1=>>TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l2=>>TestMe.cmd
@Echo SET l3=>>TestMe.cmd
```

Other stuff I wrote and `TestTweak` concludes with

```dos
call Tweak.cmd %Args%
shutdown -r -t 10
```

So when it reboots, I run the `TestMe.cmd` file. Note, `TestMe.cmd` calls `TestTweak` there by setting up the next `TestMe.cmd` file.

Basically I don't like the way I have done the new file creation. When I tried:

```dos
@Echo cd "%pth%" >TestMe.cmd
@Echo call Timer.cmd 1 %Args%>>TestMe.cmd
@Echo call Timer.cmd 2 %Args%>>TestMe.cmd
...
```

I found it would run `Timer`, and even worse, run the `TestTweak`, and then write to `TestMe`. It seems I'm having issues with overwriting `TestMe.cmd` while it's still running as well :( So I cheated by `set var=` to deal with extra characters and lines.

I tried:

```dos
Echo. | Set /p= cd %pth% >TestMe.cmd
Echo >>TestMe.cmd
```

But I kept getting *Echo is On/Off*. Trying `REM` wasn't much better as it appended to the previous lines' arguments.

This site is great - the people really helpful and good. I'm hoping someone out there can help me, because this is driving me nuts. First is how to write the file without execution, and secondary is dealing with the re-write of `TestMe`.

Thank you.

~Just a fool and his dos batch file

Comment: I'm thinking, for the recursive part, perhaps I should use 'Start' without a '/wait /b'. Any thoughts?